# pylint: unable to import 'requests' using nvim with pylsp and pylint enabled

Tags: python, neovim, pylint, nvim-lspconfig

I'm having a weird problem with pylint complaining about an import problem:

```
pylint: [import-error] Unable to import 'requests' [E0401]
```

This makes no sense since `requests` is a standard library. Also, I have no issues with importing other standard libraries.

I've tried to with pylint and pynvim installed but changes.

I use:

- neovim 0.9.1
- pylsp with pylint enabled

When I run `pylint` from the command-line, this error doesn't appear.

Below I attach a screenshot showing exactly what I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: ``requests`` is not builtin it comes from an external package. You can verify that with ``python3 -m venv venv``, ``source venv/bin/activate``, ``python3`` then 

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` is not installed in the env pylint's is run, localize where pylint is installed / run and install requests in it, for example with `pip install requests`.